# Can anyone recommend a decent DSP/speech library in C++?

Tags: c++, open-source, signal-processing, speech

Google returns too much results, although [SPUC](http://spuc.sourceforge.net/) caught my attention.
Is there a standard recommended library like OpenCV for vision?
The necessary features would be:

- Free Open Source
- filter design (Butterworth, Chebyshev, etc)
- FFT
- if possible, some speech processing features, like MFCC computation, although that's secondary, as I could use SPTK (sp-tk.sourceforge.net) for that part.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094836/voice-recognition-in-c

Comment: Did you try speex library?
www.speex.org

Comment: @dirkgently unless I fail to see smth, it's not a dup, since I'm more interested in synthesis/coding than recognition. And sadly (only for the API, though) I'm not developing in Windows.

Comment: @coelhudo thanks for the tip! It does have some nice features. Namely the noise/echo cancelation, lpc/lsp stuff will certainly come in handy some day. Did not see any filter design stuff there though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Synthesis Toolkit, https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/, has a class that can model different Phonemes.  It also has tools for all sorts of DSP including different types of filters.  I recommend checking it out as it will be a fantastic learning experience no matter what you use it for.

Comment: that's a great tip, thanks! It has a lot of the stuff I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [CMU's Sphinx library](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) with success.

Comment: Hi, what exactly have you used it for?

Comment: Two test programs... One was an application launcher... So, I was annoying my coworkers with "Launch Emacs"... "Launch X Term"...